# Set Firefox to NEVER use Cache?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

Can I set Firefox to **never** use cache?

This is for development, to be sure I am always looking at my latest work. (I might ask the same type of question for Eclipse/Tomcat too. Building a webapp with nothing but caching issues on top of caching issues can be very counter-productive. I want to be sure I'm viewing my changes.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your address bar go to "about:config" . Search for cache. Double click `network.http.use-cache` to set it to false. ([Source](http://benlancaster.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/how-to-completely-disable-firefox-cache/)) If this does not work, use the [Cache Status add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cache-status/) for Firefox. In Firefox you can also use `CTRL + SHIFT + R` to reload the page, overriding the cache.

Comment: Great. Now, how can I test this for sure? Any ideas?

Comment: [This answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1192640/823435) sums it up. I'm also editing my answer to include CTRL+SHIFT+R, the reload/override cache command in Firefox.