# How can I tell Firefox never to cache a certain server?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-cache

I know you can tell Firefox never to [use cache at all](https://superuser.com/q/390225/122798). But - can I make such a setting on a per-server level? (There is this web-based mechanism which I know I never want to get cached results for, and unfortunately, I am seeing cached versions.) I want to tell Firefox "never cache pages from some.where.com"... is this possible?

Note: I don't want to *clear* the existing cache like in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox), I want to *prevent* caching.

Comment: @harrymc: No, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to avoid caching is to browse to this website/domain using
[Private Browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history).

This will prevent adding the pages to the History list, Form history,
Downloads Window history, cookies storage,
Cached Web Content and Offline Web Content and stored User Data.